# Filter products through tags in Shopify

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to pull only the products from a collection that have a certain tag. This is my way of creating sub-collections since Shopify doesn't do this.  My code doesn't seem to be working, and I can't figure out why it isn't working. I am doing this on the collection.liquid page. It is just printing the headings to the screen, but not the list of products. Any ideas?

```
{% if collection.handle == "all" %}
  <!-- All Collections -->
    <div id="collections">
      <h2>Brave Bracelets</h2>
      <div class="product-list clearfix">
        <h3>Cerulean</h3>
        <ul>
          {% for product in collections.brave-bracelets.products %}
            {% capture alt_attr %}{{ product.title }} by The Brave Collection{% endcapture %}
            {% if product.tags contains "cerulean" %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ product.url }}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ alt_attr }}" /></a>
                <h3><a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title }}</a></h3>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- #collections -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor mistake on your capture line, which should be:

```
{% capture alt_attr %}{{ product.title }} by The Brave Collection{% endcapture %}
```

But other than that, your code worked fine for me. I pasted it into collection.liquid and changed the collection "brave-bracelets" and tag "cerulean" to a collection and tag of my own, and it displayed the list of products as expected. Maybe double check that you do have products with the tag "cerulean" in the collection "brave-bracelets"...

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I changed the mistake you found, but that still didn't seem to do it. Checked to make sure that there was a product with that tag in the collection, and there was. I'm really at a loss. Is there anything else I should check? I updated the code above with your correction.

Comment: @MikesBarto2002 It's a long shot, but I found when I was testing your code that commenting out liquid can cause strange things to happen. E.g. `<!--{% if product.tags contains "test" %}-->`. You don't have anything like that in your code do you? What happens if you remove the if statement altogether and try displaying all products in that collection?